# Terraform modules: creating multiple resources with modules and reference each other

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have defined a variable `tenants` which is a map:

```
variable tenants {
  type        = map
  default     = {
    tenant1 = {
      name      = "Tenant1"
    },
    tenant2 = {
      name    = "Tenant2"
    }
  }
}
```

In the root file, I call a module `tenant` as follows:

```
module "tenant" {
  source = "./modules/tenant"

  for_each     =    var.tenants
  tenant = each.value.name
}
```

The child module `tenant` looks as follows:

```
resource "mso_tenant" "tenant" {
  name            = var.tenant
}
```

And I have defined an output in the child module with:

```
output "mso_tenant" {
  value = mso_tenant.tenant
```

In the output file under root, I do the following to print all tenants:

```
output "tenant_names" {
    value       = { for p in sort(keys(var.tenants)) : p => module.tenant[p].mso_tenant.name }
}
```

So far so good, all the above works.

Now I have another variable called `schemas`, also a map. A tenant can have multiple schema's. So I have defined the following

```
variable schemas {
  type        = map
  default     = {
    schema1 = {
      name          = "Schema1",
      template_name = "Template1",
      tenant = <refer to tenant1>      <==== refer to tenant module
    },
    schema2 = {
      name          = "Schema2"
      template_name = "Template2",
      tenant = <refer to tenant2>      <==== refer to tenant module
    },
    schema3 = {
      name          = "Schema3"
      template_name = "Template3",
      tenant = <refer to tenant1>      <==== refer to tenant module
    },
  }
}
```

In the main.tf file under root I want to do the following:

```
module "schema" {
  source = "./modules/schema"

  for_each     =    var.schemas
  name            = each.value.name
  template_name   = each.value.template_name
  tenant_id       = each.value.tenant
}
```

How could I reference the respective tenants in either the schema variable or else directly in the schema module?

Update:

Tried solution 1:

In variables file, I passed the tenant as follows:

```
    schema1 = {
      name          = "Schema1",
      template_name = "Template1",
      tenant        = module.tenant["tenant1"].mso_tenant
    }
```

> Error: Variables not allowed

Tried solution 2:

```
module "tenant" {
  source = "./modules/tenant"

  for_each     =    var.tenants
  tenant       =    each.value.name
}

module "schema" {
  source = "./modules/schema"

  for_each     =    var.schemas
  name            = each.value.name
  template_name   = each.value.template_name
  tenant_id       = module.tenant[each.value.tenant].mso_tenant
}
```

Resulting in following error:

```
  on main.tf line 30, in module "schema":
  30:   tenant_id       = module.tenant[each.value.tenant].mso_tenant
    |----------------
    | each.value is object with 2 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "tenant".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to refer to the tenant resources of `tenant1` you can use `module.tenant["tenant1"].mso_tenant` and assign this directly to the schema or in the input variables of the second module.

As you are using module `for_each` `module.tenant` is a map of objects keyed by the tenant_id. Each object consists of all the outputs of your tenant child module.

**REFACTORED**:

root variable definitions:

```
variable tenants {
  type = map
  default = {
    tenant1 = {
      name = "Tenant1"
    },
    tenant2 = {
      name = "Tenant2"
    }
  }
}

variable schemas {
  type = map
  default = {
    schema1 = {
      name          = "Schema1",
      template_name = "Template1",
      tenant_id     = "tenant1"
    },
    schema2 = {
      name          = "Schema2"
      template_name = "Template2",
      tenant_id     = "tenant2"
    },
    schema3 = {
      name          = "Schema3"
      template_name = "Template3",
      tenant_id     = "tenant1"
    },
  }
}
```

calling the modules like this in the root:

```
module "tenant" {
  source = "./modules/tenant"

  for_each = var.tenants

  tenant = each.value.name
}

module "schema" {
  source = "./modules/schema"

  for_each = var.schemas

  name          = each.value.name
  template_name = each.value.template_name
  tenant        = module.tenant[each.value.tenant_id].mso_tenant
}
```

root output definitions could look like:

```
output "tenant_names" {
  value = { for p in sort(keys(var.tenants)) : p => module.tenant[p].mso_tenant.name }
}

output "schemas" {
  value = module.schema
}
```

this leads to the following outputs:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

schemas = {
  "schema1" = {
    "schema" = {
      "name" = "Schema1"
      "template_name" = "Template1"
      "tenant" = {
        "name" = "Tenant1"
      }
    }
  }
  "schema2" = {
    "schema" = {
      "name" = "Schema2"
      "template_name" = "Template2"
      "tenant" = {
        "name" = "Tenant2"
      }
    }
  }
  "schema3" = {
    "schema" = {
      "name" = "Schema3"
      "template_name" = "Template3"
      "tenant" = {
        "name" = "Tenant1"
      }
    }
  }
}
tenant_names = {
  "tenant1" = "Tenant1"
  "tenant2" = "Tenant2"
}
```

schema module used to simulate:

```
variable "name" {
  type = string
}

variable "template_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "tenant" {
  type = any
}

output "schema" {
  value = {
    name          = var.name
    template_name = var.template_name
    tenant        = var.tenant
  }
}
```

tenant module used to simulate:

```
variable "tenant" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  mso_tenant = {
    tenant = {
      name = var.tenant
    }
  }
}

output "mso_tenant" {
  value = local.mso_tenant.tenant
}
```

hope in the full context this is easier and more clear ;)

Comment: Thanks so much. Option 1 (passing through variable file): I get back `Variables may not be used here.` Seems like I cannot use module.tenant in a variable file. On option 2: I get always `This object does not have an attribute named "tenant".` Original question updated to reflect this.

Comment: my bad.. try using `values(var.schemas)` as you want to have a list of the values of the original map. editing my answer to reflect this

Comment: It complains on the `values(var.schemas)` with the followiing message: `The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list of object.`. Yet, my schema variable is a map.

Comment: as this is too complicated to get all things together I will add a full working example simulating the actual resources with locals ;)

Comment: sorry for the confusion.. I also added the child module si used to simulate the behavior without actually creating resources and attache the output of an apply run (used terraform 0.13.5 for this)

Comment: Thanks a million. That helps a lot. Quick question: why you create a local in fact, why not just outputting mso_tenant?

Comment: The local is just used to simulate instead of creating real resources. I don't use mso ;) you should of course use the real resources as in your example. So my two testing modules are just for pure testing. happy to have pointed you in the right direction. enjoy.